# Inline function call error

Tags: c++, c, linux, g++

In one header file, i have a inline function define like bellow:

```
extern CMODEXPORT int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
(
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec,     /* I: Feature record */
    FMI_delete_fn_p_t  fn        /* I: Function pointer */
);

template<class T>
inline int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class(FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec) // I: Feature record
{
  class FMIHelper
  {
    public:
      static int DeleteParms(FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec)
      {
        //....
        return error;
      }
  };
  return FMI_invoke_delete_as_class(frec, &FMIHelper::DeleteParms);
}
```

In the last line, there is a call of `FMI_invoke_delete_as_class`
This function is defined in another .c file like

```
extern int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
(
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec,     /* I: Feature record */
    OM_class_t         class_id  /* I: Object class */
)
{
    //...
}

extern int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
(
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec,     /* I: Feature record */
    FMI_delete_fn_p_t  fn        /* I: Function pointer */
)
```

if the declare of FMI_invoke_delete_as_class in header file is before inline function like i posted, inline funtion's call is ok. However if i put that declaration after that inline function, it calls the wrong function in .c file.
I don't know why, just happens under linux.

Comment: Could you substiture/provide definition for your custom types? It would be easier to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed with following code:

```
/** kk.h */
#include <iostream>
struct FEATURE_RECORD_p_t
{
    int kk;
};

template<class T>
inline int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class(FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec) // I: Feature record
{
    class FMIHelper
    {
        public:
            static int DeleteParms(FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec)
            {
                //....
                std::cout << "DeleteParms" << std::endl;
                frec.kk = 100;
                return frec.kk;
            }
    };

    std::cout << "FMI_invoke_delete_as_class<>" << std::endl;
    return FMI_invoke_delete_as_class(frec, &FMIHelper::DeleteParms);
}

typedef int (*FMI_delete_fn_p_t)(FEATURE_RECORD_p_t);

extern int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
(
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec,     /* I: Feature record */
    FMI_delete_fn_p_t  fn        /* I: Function pointer */
);
```

and

```
#include "kk.h"
extern int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
(
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t  frec,     /* I: Feature record */
    int                 class_id  /* I: Object class */
)
{
    std::cout << "FMI_invoke_delete_as_class (bad)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

extern int FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
(
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t frec,     /* I: Feature record */
    FMI_delete_fn_p_t  fn        /* I: Function pointer */
)
{
    std::cout << "FMI_invoke_delete_as_class" << std::endl;
    return fn(frec);
}

int main()
{
    FEATURE_RECORD_p_t kk;

    FMI_invoke_delete_as_class<int>(kk);
    return 0;
}
```

and printed result is:

```
FMI_invoke_delete_as_class<>
FMI_invoke_delete_as_class
DeleteParms
```

It seams ok. How do you invoke inline function? How are your type definitions? Which is your compile command? I'm using `g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)` with `g++ -g -o kk kk.cpp` command line

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know very clearly the compiler version and complain command. Because i use our company's own build command. I thought this is an common problem.